# Gazebo_ros launch

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, python, urdf

all !!
Try to do first project https://github.com/Dizog84/articubot_one
making all as joshnewans teach) youtube articulatedrobotics.xyz

Steps before

I have 22.04 Ubuntu LTS ros2-humble

Stay on second lesson:

> denis@denis-HP-ProBook-6470b:~$ ros2 launch articubot_one
> rsp.launch.py [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below
> /home/denis/.ros/log/2024-01-13-18-19-14-645734-denis-HP-ProBook- 6470b-8353
> [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO [INFO]
> [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [8354]
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1705133954.842664897]
> [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1705133954.842785685]
> [robot_state_publisher]: got segment castor_wheel
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1705133954.842801088]
> [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1705133954.842811437]
> [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1705133954.842820732]
> [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel

Try to start gazebo with ros

> denis@denis-HP-ProBook-6470b:/$ ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py
> [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/denis/.ros/log/2024-01-13-18-19-45-501464-denis-HP-ProBook-6470b-8373
> [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
> [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for
> traceback): 'visualize.rviz' is not a valid package name

Any thoughts ? Where should I search for
gazebo.launch.py is default as download

denis@denis-HP-ProBook-6470b:~$ ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py --debug
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_context]: emitting event synchronously: 'launch.events.IncludeLaunchDescription'
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/denis/.ros/log/2024-01-15-10-45-26-613258-denis-HP-ProBook-6470b-25462
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to DEBUG
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.include_launch_description.IncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x7ff55ba3f190>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.include_launch_description.IncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x7ff55ba3f190>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_include_launch_description.OnIncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x7ff55ba3f310>'
<launch.substitutions.this_launch_file_dir.ThisLaunchFileDir object at 0x7ff55c6e7df0>
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_description_source]: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_description_source.py", line 68, in try_get_launch_description_without_context
perform_substitutions(context, self.__location)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in 
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 240, in perform_substitution
return substitution.perform(self)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/substitutions/this_launch_file_dir.py", line 56, in perform
raise SubstitutionFailure(
launch.substitutions.substitution_failure.SubstitutionFailure: ThisLaunchFileDir used outside of a launch file (in a script)

[DEBUG] [launch.launch_description_source]: Failed to load the launch file without a context: ThisLaunchFileDir used outside of a launch file (in a script)
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_description_source]: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_description_source.py", line 68, in try_get_launch_description_without_context
perform_substitutions(context, self.__location)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in 
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 240, in perform_substitution
return substitution.perform(self)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/substitutions/this_launch_file_dir.py", line 56, in perform
raise SubstitutionFailure(
launch.substitutions.substitution_failure.SubstitutionFailure: ThisLaunchFileDir used outside of a launch file (in a script)

[DEBUG] [launch.launch_description_source]: Failed to load the launch file without a context: ThisLaunchFileDir used outside of a launch file (in a script)
[DEBUG] [launch]: An exception was raised in an async action/event
[DEBUG] [launch]: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 336, in run_async
raise completed_tasks_exceptions[0]
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 230, in _process_one_event
await self.__process_event(next_event)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 250, in __process_event
visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
[Previous line repeated 1 more time]
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
return self.execute(context)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/actions/include_launch_description.py", line 148, in execute
launch_description = self.__launch_description_source.get_launch_description(context)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_description_source.py", line 84, in get_launch_description
self._get_launch_description(self.__expanded_location)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_description_sources/python_launch_description_source.py", line 51, in _get_launch_description
return get_launch_description_from_python_launch_file(location)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_description_sources/python_launch_file_utilities.py", line 68, in get_launch_description_from_python_launch_file
return getattr(launch_file_module, 'generate_launch_description')()
File "/opt/ros/humble/share/gazebo_ros/launch/gzserver.launch.py", line 65, in generate_launch_description
model, plugin, media = GazeboRosPaths.get_paths()
File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scripts/gazebo_ros_paths.py", line 45, in get_paths
package_share_path = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ament_index_python/packages.py", line 80, in get_package_share_directory
path = os.path.join(get_package_prefix(package_name), 'share', package_name)
File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ament_index_python/packages.py", line 55, in get_package_prefix
raise ValueError(
ValueError: 'visualize.rviz' is not a valid package name

[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): 'visualize.rviz' is not a valid package name
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_context]: emitting event: 'launch.events.Shutdown'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7ff55ba3eda0>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7ff55ba3eda0>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_shutdown.OnShutdown object at 0x7ff55ba3dc90>'

Comment: That launch file is in the gazebo_ros package as you've called it. Please take some time to clearly explain your problem and show what you've done already to debug. And from there people will be able to help you more.

Comment: I`ve just find this launch files in gazebo_ros pkg (path /opt/ros/humble/share/gazebo_ros/launch/gazebo.launch.py) look at them /opt/ros/humble/share/gazebo_ros/launch# ls
gazebo.launch.py  gzclient.launch.py  gzserver.launch.py  spawn_entity_demo.launch.py
they are standard PY script with imported a lot of Classes from launch module And for me difficult to debug so pure information ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): 'visualize.rviz' is not a valid package name . Is there any extended debug  with information what`s really happening and triggered this error